# How to listen HTTP post requests behind ipfs gateway?

Tags: http, post, ipfs

I was able to create a website with a domain name behind a ipfs gateway like cloudflare.

Can I listen HTTP post requests ?

A ipfs website like torrent-paradise.ml, seems to send HTTP post requests (ex: /api/search?q=test)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC the website you mentioned uses old school nodejs app for the `/api/search` endpoint.

Search feature is not provided by the IPFS daemon.

---

By default IPFS gateway allows only HTTP GET.

One can enable experimental Writable Gateway feature, which then accepts HTTP POST: https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/writeable-http-gateways/210?u=lidel, but it only allows you to import data to IPFS. There is no search feature.

That being said, I believe you should not care about HTTP method used, but ask "how to build dynamic app on IPFS" or "how to do search using immutable data on IPFS" instead.

Some pointers/ideas:

- Build a DAG-based index and put it on IPFS, then have your app traverse the graph while looking for answer (fetching only subset of the index, only when needed)
- Leverage [libp2p's pubsub](https://docs.libp2p.io/concepts/publish-subscribe/) for real-time features (eg. by running js-ipfs on the page)
- Look into [CRDTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type) for decentralized conflict-free data types

While you can do it all by hand and tailor your solution to a specific problem, reusable primitives for the last two are provided by existing projects built on top of IPFS,  like [OrbitDB](https://orbitdb.org/).